# Should I use Django or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django

I’m thinking about which software I should use for my web-app. What about Node.js or Django for the back-end? I want to create an online preparation course for the final school exams in my country. At the beginning for maths. The course should contain tutorials and a lot of exercises of different types. E.g. multiple choice, user text/number input and drawing tasks. The exercises should change (different levels) with the learning progress. Wrong questions should asked again with different numbers. I also want a score system and statistics. So far, I have got only limited web development skills. (some HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and Wordpress). I don’t know JavaScript or Python.

Possible pros for Python / Django:
-   easy syntax, easier to learn for me as a beginner
-   fast development, earlier release
-   libraries for mathematical and scientific computation

Possible pros for JavaScript / Node.js:
-   great performance, better choice for real time applications: user should get the answer for a question quickly

Which software would you use in my case? Are my arguments for Python/NodeJS right? Which kind of database would you use?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find a good framework to build on, Django is getting to give you the most return for your time. Node.js is infinitely powerful, but you need to have serious software development chops to create a great solution with it.

With Django, you'll have thousands of packages targeted specifically at making web app implementation easy. Node.js will have a lot of similar packages, but it's much more general purpose.

I know it sounds wishy-washy, but you can make either path work, but Django would be friendlier for your purposes.